# gcc shared_ptr copy assignment implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, shared-ptr, libstdc++

I was scanning the `shared_ptr` implementation in GCC 5, and I see the following:

```
  __shared_ptr&
  operator=(__shared_ptr&& __r) noexcept
  {
    __shared_ptr(std::move(__r)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }
```

My question is why the additional move construct of the temporary *before* the swap? I assume that the compilation will remove any additional overhead - but why not just call `__r.swap(*this)`? Is there some clever side effect that I'm missing?

I see that other functions in the class are also implemented using the same pattern, I can understand cases which accept a const reference, but an rvalue reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a start, that's what the standard says, GCC just follows it to the letter.

That way the assignment operator has a postcondition that `__r.empty()` which would not be achieved by your suggestion, so implementing it as you suggest would have different effects to what the standard says, and so would be non-conforming.

i.e. this assertion holds:

```
auto p1 = std::make_shared<int>(1);
auto p2 = std::make_shared<int>(2);
p1 = std::move(p2);
assert( !p2 );
```

The "clever side effect" is that you create a new *empty* shared_ptr, which ends up holding the old value of `*this` after the swap, and then goes out of scope. That means the old value of `*this` doesn't end up in `__r`.

Comment: this makes sense, one of these days I should stop procrastinating and scan the standard...

Answer (score 1):

Because we need to call a destructor on the rvalue referenced to decrease the instance count.

Answer (score 1):

By moving the guts of `__r` into a temporary that is destroyed as the function `return`s, it is made sure that the moved-away-from object `__r` refers to is left in an empty state. I guess they wanted to keep that logic at one place, the move constructor, which looks like this.

```
__shared_ptr(__shared_ptr&& __r) noexcept
  : _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), _M_refcount()
{
  _M_refcount._M_swap(__r._M_refcount);
  __r._M_ptr = 0;
}
```

Personally, I prefer the following implementation which, to my best knowledge,  is equivalent.

```
widget&
operator=(widget&& other) noexcept
{
  widget temp {};
  swap(*this, temp);
  swap(*this, other);
  return *this;
}
```

It can be complemented with a move constructor that is implemented like this.

```
widget(widget&& other) noexcept : widget {}
{
  swap(*this, other);
}
```

I'm assuming that there is a

```
void
swap(widget&, widget&) noexcept;
```

overload that ADL can find and that the default-constructor of `widget` is `noexcept`.

Comment: Erm, your implementation says that you must default-construct a `widget` as part of doing an assignment, and says that you have to move/copy the contents of a widget twice?

Comment: @AndreKostur That's right, except that it is always a move and never a a copy.

Comment: I agree, the widget itself would get moved twice, however any member of widget which doesn't support move would be copied twice.

Comment: Of course, if `widget` has a large embedded array, then this is probably a bad idea. But as its author, you'll know that. I found that most of the time, classes where you need to write custom move operations merely consist of very few (like two or three) pointers and integers.